# How can I know which tables "compose" a view?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to create a trigger on SYS.database_mirroring as it is not a real table, just a view... I can't do it.

I want to know were the field mirroring_state_desc is coming from so that I can create a trigger on that table when it is changed.

How can I know which tables are used to create that view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I know which store procedure or trigger is using a table on SQL Server 2008 R2?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/how-can-i-know-which-store-procedure-or-trigger-is-using-a-table-on-sql-server-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to an article that shows a [few different ways to show VIEW code](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/03/3-different-ways-to-display-view.html).

Essentially, you run "exec sp_helptext [view_name]"; obviously exchanging [view_name] with the name of your view.

From with SQL Server Management Studio, you can locate the view in the "views" node, right-click on it, and obtain the code behind it by clicking "CREATE TO" and then a location.

Lastly, you can run the following SQL against INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME as ViewName, VIEW_DEFINITION as ViewDefinition
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views
```

Of course, given the limit of 4000 characters, a better option would be:

```
SELECT name, object_definition(object_id)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE [type] 'v'
```

Answer (score 6):

To take some action when a database mirroring state change occurs, you have several options including WMI and Event Notifications (using the DATABASE_MIRRORING_STATE_CHANGE [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190655.aspx)):

[Altering on Database Mirroring Events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966392.aspx)

If you are doing any sort of work with mirroring, I can recommend (MVP & MCM) Robert Davis' book:

[Pro SQL Server 2008 Mirroring](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430224231)

Answer (score 3):

You should use

- [OBJECT_DEFINITION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx)
- [sys.all_sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184389.aspx)
- [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx)
- Red Gate SQL Search (free)

You don't use

- INFORMATION_SCHEMA because the [VIEW_DEFINITION column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181381.aspx) is nvarchar(4000) and you may not get all data
- sp_helptext because you get multiple lines of nvarchar(255)

But you won't be able to set up a trigger on the sys schema